# R - how to use bind_rows with non existing dataframes

Tags: r, dplyr

Lets say that I have this code

```
dt <-
  data.frame(
    nr = seq(1: 150) %>%
    mutate(x = 1) 
  )




if (nrow(dt %>% filter(nr <= 100)) > 0) {
  
  a <-
    dt %>% 
    filter(nr <= 100)
  
} 


if (nrow(dt %>% filter(nr > 100 & nr <= 200)) > 0) {

  b <-
    dt %>% 
    filter(nr > 100 & nr <= 200)
  
} 


if (nrow(dt %>% filter(nr > 200)) > 0) {
  
  c <-
    dt %>% 
    filter(nr > 200)
  
}



bind_rows(a, b, c)
```

Bind rows will return error because there is no c dataframe. How can I avoid it and but to bind rows only existing elements? Please keep in mind, that at the very end colnames may be different and result must be dataframe not list or anything else.

Comment: I recommend against assigning anything to `c`. `c` is the base R combine function.

Comment: when you write `data.frame(nr = seq(1: 150) %>% mutate(x = 1))` do you mean `data.frame(nr = seq(1: 150)) %>% mutate(x = 1)` ? If so, you could just write it as `data.frame(nr = seq(1: 150), x = 1)`

Comment: Having objects only conditionally exist is a very unusual design choice. What is the use case for this?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
bind_rows(mget(intersect(ls(), c("a", "b", "c"))))
```

- with `ls()` you are getting a vector of all the existing objects in the environment
- with `intersect()` you get select only the obects you need. In this case `a` `b` `c` [`c` being a really poor choice --> see @Ian Campbell in the comments]
- `mget` returns a list of the objects

---

However, I agree with @bcarlsen in the comments. It is pretty unusual to define your code this way.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(mget(letters[1:3]))
```